# Can apps identify me after I reinstall an app, such as by my Apple ID?

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-id

I'm trying to make this app "forget" me and not be able to identify me when I install it again. I'm on my iPad Air 2 with iOS 10.1.1.

I read on another question that they cannot see your unique device identifier anymore. Are they able to persist data in any way (I have iCloud turned off), or can they view my Apple ID? Do I need to perform a full reset?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you haven't identified the app in question we can only provide fairly generic advice. One thing apps *can* do is view identifiers such as the media access control (MAC) address. This is not to be confused with Mac as in Apple Mac.

The MAC address of a device is a **unique** identifier assigned to network interfaces for the purpose of communications. Most IEEE 802 network technologies, including Ethernet and Wi-Fi, use MAC addresses. Devices that have MAC addresses are not just computers, smartphones and tablets. They can include anything that connects to a network (e.g. printers, smart TVs, weather stations, etc).

If you're concerned about a particular app, you should take the time to read its privacy policy.

If your question is really about something else, such as wanting to change accounts used for the app, you may be best to contact the developer directly or use their support pages.

**[EDIT]**

As suggested by bmike in comments, I'm updating this answer to include info on changes that Apple are enforcing as of the soon-to-be-released iOS 10.3 update.

Up until now, keychain data in iOS remained on the device even after the app was deleted from the device. After upgrading to iOS 10.3 deleting an app will also delete all associated keychain contents for that app **unless** its keychain item is shared with other apps. In that event, the keychain data won't be deleted until those other apps are also deleted.

Apple's intention with this is to further protect user privacy by ensuring that any information that can identify a user is not left on the device after the app that saved it is removed from the device.

**In a nutshell - anyone concerned about their personal data should upgrade to iOS 10.3 if their device supports it.**

Comment: Apple is pushing changes on 10.x to crack down / restrict saving items in the keychain and possibly iCloud so that when you delete an app, the "cookie crumbs" left behind are removed. Perhaps a part of this answer is to update to the latest 10.x at your earliest convenience after a backup.

Comment: @bmike Thanks bmike, good suggestion. I've updated my answer to provide some context and info on this.

Comment: Is keychain data really essential? The app could store the data online.

Comment: @vsz It's not so much that keychain data is essential. But in this case the OP's question was about whether an app could identify them **after** it was removed and then re-installed again on the same device. In this case, an app that had saved data online could not identify them again without somehow matching the local installation with a pre-existing account/data online. The only way it could do that would be if the OP re-entered their credentials or if some data was retained locally from the previous installation, or saved to iCloud (which the OP says was switched off).

Comment: @Monomeeth : a really devious app could store data in a picture's metadata or as a watermark, if it has access to the photo albums, or do some other tricks.

Comment: @vsz Almost anything is possible - but we can't eliminate risk. I spent years helping change a government organisation that was extremely risk averse - all their policies were geared towards _eliminating_ risk. It took a long time, but now they get what they were doing cost more in terms of $, productivity, staff morale, etc. (They didn't even allow internet access for over 99% of their 30,000 staff). My point is, we need to _manage_ risk. On iOS that _usually_ means don't jailbreak, keep the OS updated, read privacy policies,  make informed decisions before giving apps access to things, etc.

Comment: App store applications cannot identify your MAC address in native code m. The lower level APIs to access this information have obfuscated it for years now.... you can only get the MAC address through an enterprise deployment with special entitlements or on a jailbroken phone.

Answer (score 5):

iOS App store apps (on stock, non-jailbroken, iOS 10 devices) can no longer directly get the device's MAC address.  The current iOS 10 APIs return a generic fake MAC address.  There is no API for an app to get your Apple ID (unless you get the user to voluntarily manually type it into the app) or Unique ID in iOS 10 (only very early iOS versions, e.g. iOS 3, etc., may have allowed this).

However, some apps can store persistent data in your device's Keychain (used by iOS to store passwords, etc.)  If you delete an app, it may be possible for a re-installed app to see if previous keychain contents exist.  The only way to completely delete all Keychain data might be to Erase all Contents and Settings, and set up the device as new.

Comment: The inability for apps to no longer get the real MAC address was included with iOS 10.2. Earlier versions of iOS (including iOS 10.1.1 used by the OP) still allowed apps to ascertain the device's MAC address. However, you do highlight an important point I neglected to mention, so +1 for that. :)

Comment: Future version of iOS might also delete Keychain data when an app is deleted.